# Formatting a column based on IF and AND related to another cell

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to make a performance tracker for trainees at work, which tracks their KPIs based on which week of training they're in but I'm having trouble getting the formatting to work.

Basically, I want the following:

If Cell C4 contains "Week 1" and the value in Cell D4 is equal to or greater than (value on sheet 2, cell B6 * 0.9) then colour the cell green.

The formula I was trying to sue is this: IF($C$4="Week 1")and(D4=>((KPI!B6)*0.9))

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

Comment: AND is a function in Excel, not an operator. Should be `IF(AND($C$4="Week 1", D4>=KPI!B6*0.9),...) `

Comment: I don't have a copy of 2010 available to me. In 2013, use conditional formatting with a formula, and set that formula to `=AND($C$4="Week 1", D4>=KPI!B6*0.9)` (thanks, Máté). Set green as your fill colour for the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

*You need to use this Formula for `Conditional Formatting:`*

```
=AND($C$4="Week1",$D$4>=KPI!$B$6*0.9)
```